# Add ArrayCollection of Entities in the same entity type

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.8

Is it possible to keep an array of entities A in the entity A ? How to do this with Doctrine ?

I have :

```
class A {
   /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     */
    private $sisters;
}
```

But I don't know what to add to have Doctrine do what I need.

Comment: Can you expalin more you'r question ? what do mean with "keep an array of entities A in the entity A" ??

Comment: That is part of my problem, I don't find the words to explain :(

In my 'exemple', I want sisters to be an arrayCollection of type A

Comment: for example my own sisters cant be your sisters , that's why the relation should be one to many relation, i think my solution is correct !!!

Comment: OneToMany does not work, imagine the following scenario, `A`, `B` and `C` sisters, when you add `B` and `C` as sister of `A`, with OneToMany you are setting `A` as parent of `B` and `C` (it's not real), then `B` and `C` has a field called **parent_sister** with `A`. Now  try to add `C` as sister of `B`, you are overriding the `parent_sister` of `C` and setting `B`, then `C` is not more sister of `A`? think in a real world, one sister is not parent of another, the only way to know sisters is knowing a common parent of each one, then the joinTable act as a record to know the relation of sisters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` can have many sisters, and many sisters can be sister of `A` (Many-To-Many, Self-referencing):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table()
 */
class A
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\A")
     */
    private $sisters;
}
```

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing

Comment: i think my own sisters cant be your sisters , that's why the relation should be one to many relation ,think my solution is correct !!!

Comment: OneToMany does not work, imagine the following scenario, `A`, `B` and `C` sisters, when you add `B` and `C` as sister of `A`, with OneToMany you are setting `A` as parent of `B` and `C` (it's not real), then `B` and `C` has a field called **parent_sister** with `A`. Now  try to add `C` as sister of `B`, you are overriding the `parent_sister` of `C` and setting `B`, then `C` is not more sister of `A`? think in a real world, one sister is not parent of another, the only way to know sisters is knowing a common parent of each one, then the joinTable act as a record to know the relation of sisters.